# Binding a string parameter to Enum type in AzureFunction

Tags: azure, enums, azure-functions, custom-model-binder, defaultmodelbinder

I am trying to bind a string route parameter to Enum Type like below

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "ValidateKey/{keyType}/{key}")]HttpRequestMessage req, KeyType keyType, string key, TraceWriter log)
```

The code is giving me following exception when I hit the endpoint.

> Exception binding parameter 'req' -> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'MyCommon.KeyType'."

The model binder is not able to bind the string parameter to Enum type.
In a MVC or WebAPI application,  binding to Enum works fine, but it seems like the binding is not supported in AzureFunction.
Is there anyway to plugin a custom ModelBinder in AzureFunction to make it work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The binding process is a bit different and we do not currently expose a mechanism to plug custom binders in.

I've opened this issue to address the specific issue, where we don't currently support binding to enums: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1564

In the meantime, there are a few workarounds but the most straight forward one would be to bind to a string and parse that parameter to your enum as part of your function. Not ideal, but a simple one liner:

```
Enum.TryParse(keyTypeValue, out KeyType keyType);
```